# How do I reduce the DC output voltage of a power supply?

Tags: power-supply

I have a DC power supply which takes 240V AC as an input, and steps down to 30V AC with a 200VA step down transformer c/w rectifiers, but the output voltage which I get is about 43-44V DC. The voltage which I need to get in the output is in a range of 32V DC to 33V DC.

How can I reduce the output voltage down from 44V DC to 33V DC without changing my transformer, considering that my current requirement is about 5-6A?

Comment: I've submitted an edit to your question to improve its quality, but in future please make an effort to use correct spelling, punctuation and grammar. We understand that English may not be your first language, but simple things like properly capitalising and not using five sets of punctuation (e.g. ?????) when one will do makes your question much easier to read.

Comment: Is the output of your supply filtered and if so, what's the value of the reservoir capacitor(s)?  Also, what does "c/w rectifiers" mean?

Answer (score 2):

30VAC when rectified becomes approximately \$\sqrt2\$ higher minus a couple of diode volt drops of around 0.7 v each. this means the DC supply will be about 41 volts. On no-load this could easily be 43 volts give or take an inexact transformer turns ratio.

So that's the explanation - if you want approximately 33 volts DC you need a transformer with a 23 volt AC output.

Another way (without dissipating a load of heat) is to use a switching regulator to take the 40 odd volts and convert it efficiently to 30 odd volts. A buck regulator is what you need however, it may be a little noisy for audio so it's better to use a buck regulator to take it to maybe 34 volts then a low drop out linear regulator to provide a smooth 33 volts.

Comment: If the system is well balanced - a 33Vx6A =200VA transformer then at 6A load, won't the RMS rather than the peak matter? In which case a linear regulator will be dropping only 3V, giving >90% efficiency, as good as most switching converters.

Comment: The problem is that the rectified output varies at twice the mains frequency. At its peak, it produces the sqrt 2 x RMS value found above. This peak value is stored in an output capacitor. If the load current is not negligible, the capacitor discharges between rectifier peaks (it's called ripple voltage). The greater the load current the greater the ripple voltage. The only way to reduce the ripple is to increase capacitance. This is on top of the regulator 3 volts.

Comment: What Andy is saying is once you add your load the voltage might be less than what you need.  (Sorry Andy just not sure that was clear.)  If the output with load was 30-31 V would that still work for you?

Comment: @JoshBeam, if the load current is constant then that *would* work, but it was also dissipate 66 Watts. There are high power resistors out there that fit the bill but ultimately you are just wasting energy. A buck regulator as suggested is far more efficient.

Comment: @sherrellbc, okay makes sense. For anyone else reading, my comment that sherrellbc replied to was " can you use a 1.83 Ohm resistor to get an 11V drop?".